# When I change the variable that is in an array, why does it not update the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, variable-assignment

Essentially my question is that, in C and C++, if I update a variable that I have previously placed in an array, why does it not update the array?

Ex:

```
int var = 0;  
int list[1];  
list[0] = var;  
var = 1;

printf("%i", list[0]);
```

I don't understand why it is printing `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: `list[0] = var;` copies the value in `var` into `list[0]` - `var` and `list[0]` are two separate `int`s

Comment: Because the assignment is copying the *current* value of the variable. It is not "binding" it forever.

Comment: Unlike, say, a spreadsheet with dependencies, there is no tie created between `list[0]` and `var`. The `list[0] = var;` is a once-only assignment.

Comment: What if you do `int var = 1; int rav; rav = var; var = 2; printf("%i", rav);` do you understand what it prints?

Answer (score 2):

The variable `var` is a separate object relative to the array `list`

```
int var = 0;  
int list[1];
```

They occupy different extents of memory.

In this assignment

```
list[0] = var;
```

the copy of the value of the variable `var` is assigned to another object `list[0]`. `var` and `list[0]` have no any relation between each other.

You could declare an array of pointers like for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int var = 0;  
    int * list[1];

    list[0] = &var;

    var = 1;

    printf( "*list[0] = %d\n", *list[0] );  
}
```

The program output is

```
*list[0] = 1
```

In this case the pointer `list[0]` points to the variable `var`. So using the pointer you can output the current value of the variable `var`.

Pay attention to that even in C++ you may not declare an array of references. Similarly to the shown above approach with pointers you could declare an array of objects pf the type `std::reference_wrapper` as for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int var = 0;  
    std::reference_wrapper<int> list[1] = { var };

    var = 1;

    std::cout << "list[0] = " << list[0].get() << '\n';  
}
```

The program output is

```
list[0] = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`list[0] = var;` copies the value in `var` into `list[0]` - `var` and `list[0]` are two separate `int`s.

If you want changes to one variable to be seen through another varible, you need to use pointers or references. Example:

```c
int main() {
    int var = 0;  
    int* list[1];   // an array of pointers to `int`
    list[0] = &var; // list[0] now points at `var` 
    var = 1;
    printf("%i\n", *list[0]); // dereferencing list[0] to get the value in `var`
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Or more commonly, to set all items to one, `int list[...]` with `for(int *var = list, *end = var + sizeof list / sizeof *list; var < end; var++) *var = 1;`. That is, a list of `int` with a pointer index.